# Find section of string in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

Following on from this question:

[Select first complete string matching partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897494/select-first-complete-string-matching-partial-string/16897618#16897618)

I am storing an external sites html in a variable.  I want to search that variable for the 4th copy of 'Was it enough?' and then take the 'Yes' or 'No' that sits directly after it.  A snippet of the external HTML is:

```
    <section class="top media" style="display:block;">
    <a href="http://wasitenough.com/image/52215562284"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/438cd1f5e94c87e32dd14bbe869469b1/tumblr_mnx64jj7kf1spmjuzo1_1280.jpg" alt="Venue: Crussh
    Dish: Chicken teriyaki noodle soup

    Was it enough? No&nbsp;"> </a>
   </section>
```

My current code returns every instance.

```
$(content).find('*:contains("Was it enough")').each(function(index, crntNode){

        var parts = $(crntNode).text().split('?');
        var flag = parts[1].trim();

        console.log('The flag was ' + flag);

        if(flag == 'Yes') {
            console.log('It was enough');
            $('#yesNo').text('It was enough');
        } else if (flag == 'No') {
            console.log('It was not enough');
            $('#yesNo').text('It was not enough');
        } else if (flag != 'No' && flag != 'Yes') {
            console.log('We are not sure if it was enough');
            $('#yesNo').text('We are not sure if it was enough');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to select the fourth element? Use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: You're console logging the `flag`, and you do realize it would be `No "> ` with that markup ?

Comment: Strike that! That text is inside the `alt` attribute, so the flag would be empty.